# Is it possible to Authorize by uri?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api

I want to prevent the world from browsing to my webapi.
I do not want my users to login or use OATH or anything like that.
I email them a unique uri.
I want the users to submit from this uri and the webapi to authenticate and then authorize based on the uri and not let public getting access to the webapi uri.

Is there something built into the Authorize attribute which might help?

Use Case:

1. Admin generates token.
2. Add it to url as querystring.
3. Email url to client.
4. Url opens and token in querystring is evaluated on client  and
       fields    filled.
5. Client adds content and submits through Post to  webapi PUT.
6. Fields are submitted.
7. **Webapi PUT should only available to the Post from that url with query string.**

Comment: What's to prevent some crawler or other such bot-type mechanism from scanning around and find said "unique" uri? Or are you using the uri as a token of sorts?

Comment: I am using a generated unique token yes.

Comment: Can you share what is deriving this requirement?

Comment: Generate token. add it to url as querystring. email url to client. url opens and token in querystring is evaluated on client and fields filled. client adds content and submits through Post to webapi PUT. Fields are submitted. Requirement is that the webapi PUT is only available to the Post from that url with query string.